# PHP changing class while running

Tags: php, html, css, dom

I've a problem with loading new class from my CSS file. Actually, I think it is some thing else because if I try to change the background to red just to check if it is working, nothing happens

```
function logging_error()
{
    $html = new DOMDocument();
    @$html->loadHTML("login.php");
    $divToShake = $html->getElementsById('login_form');
    $divToShake->setAttribute("background-color", "red");
    $divToShake->item(0)->class = 'shake';
    //echo $divToShake->getAttribute('class') ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have an extra **s** in `getElementsById()`. It should be:

```
$divToShake = $html->getElementById('login_form');
```

Comment: oh my ! sorry i spent so much time figuring it out but after changing i just get blank page :(

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
$divToShake->setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
```

or maybe this

```
$divToShake->setAttribute("background", "red");
```